# Problem with URL rewrite of host-header in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use [ManagedFusion UrlRewriter](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com) module on my main/root web site to redirect requests with a certain host name to a sub-folder of the root.  Let's say my root is called `profkroot.com`, and it has a sub-folder (ASP.NET application) called `cottages`.  I also have a domain called `profkcottages.com`, which I'm trying to redirect to `profkroot.com/cottages`.

Using the following example rule, I get a totally borked rewritten URL.  I grok the regex side of the rule, but I don't know enough about the rewrite part.

Here is the rule in place on `profkroot.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Fix missing trailing slash char on folders
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} (.*)
RewriteRule ([^.?]+[^.?/]) http\://%1$1/ [R]

#Emulate profkcottages.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} (?:www\.)?profkcottages\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /cottages$1 [NC,L]
```

Here is the rewritten url if I request `http://profcottages/home.aspx`:

```
http://profkcottages.com/http/://profkcottages.com/home/.http/://profkcottages.comaspx/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had the `RewriterModule` added twice; once under `System.Web`, for IIS6 (hosted) and once under `System.WebServer`, for IIS7 (local).  Still not working 100% with css and img content, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS and image content is an easy one, the rules you have are not handling them correctly.

Comment: OK, any hints on why the rules are not handling them correctly?

Comment: A couple reasons, you could be using relative URL's for your images and CSS, which is the most likely cause.  The second is that your images content exist in the cottages directory the same way they are being requested.  Try enable logging 

RewriteLog "log.txt"
RewriteLogLevel 9

and see what the URL's are coming through as for images.